# Is the ring of rational functions a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I read that given a ring $R$, the *ring of rational functions* $R(x)$ is defined to be the set
$$
\{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}: f(x), g(x)\in R[x], g(x)\neq 0\}.
$$
My question is: is this a field? It seems to me a field because for every nonzero element $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, it has an inverse $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$. If this is not a field then is it a field if $R$ is a field?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a proper definition. What does the "$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$" even mean? Once you clarify it, it should be easier to figure it out.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121981/field-of-fractions-of-rx) for the definition. It is the field of fractions of the ring $R[x]$, where $R$ is an integral domain.

Comment: You cannot define this for any ring. You need $R$ to be an integral domain. And in this case, it's not like we just define rational functions as formal fractions. We define this as the field of fractions (so yes, this is a field) of $R[x]$. Any integral domain has a field of fractions, you can read in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions

Comment: @DietrichBurde the field of fractions is well defined only for domains, in which case it is obviously a field.

Comment: @freakish I was still typing this, yes. The duplicate says that $R$ is a domain anyway ( I assume that this duplicate is what the OP really needs, but I will ask).

Comment: @DietrichBurde This link doesn't really explain anything about what the field of fractions is.

Comment: @Mark Actually we don't need $R$ to be a domain  - simply change the restriction from *nonzero* denominator to *non-zero-divisor*, which yields the [total fraction ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_ring_of_fractions).

Comment: @BillDubuque Didn't know it has a special name. Of course we can define localizations in any ring, letting the denominators be elements from any multiplicative set. But I believe OP didn't learn that yet.

Comment: @Mark Of course, but the denominators need to be non-zero-divisors else the construction will kill some elements, i.e. the construction will not yield an *extension* (embedding) of the base ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is not a proper definition. You did not define the $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ symbol. Typically by the ring of rational functions we understand [the field of fractions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions) of the polynomial ring $R[X]$. Which covers important details behind  $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ symbol, and I encourage you to read about it. But that is well defined only when $R$ is an integral domain to begin with. In which case $R(X)$ indeed is a field.

It is possible to have a more general construction, namely [localization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)), but then the condition "$g(x)\neq 0$" is wrong (for localization to work with such condition $R$ needs to be an integral domain). But on the bright side it won't necessarily produce a field (depending on the condition of course).

Comment: To clarify: even if $R$ is not a domain we can still extend $R$ to a ring containing inverses of all elements that are not zero divisors (e.g. by localization or a quotient construction) - see the [total fraction ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_ring_of_fractions).

Comment: Thank you! @freakish